# Fails on encountering null

Tags: c#

This code is part of a Shopify Sync utility. Never has failed, until we encountered a product with no value in the CompareTo Shopify field, not that we have a product with no CompareTo value.

```
private Decimal? GetComparePrice(long? productId, long? variantId, List<Product> products)
{
    var product = products.Where(x => x.Id == productId).FirstOrDefault();
    var variantData = product.Variants.Where(x => x.Id == variantId).FirstOrDefault();

    return variantData != null ? variantData.CompareAtPrice : null;
}
```

How do I get my function to return `null` if the `CompareTo` value is `null`?

Comment: On what line does the exception happen? And what is the exception message?

Comment: Surround with `try - catch` block and in that `exception` return a default value such as `0` or a `negative number` or `something you like`

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad: It's far better to *expect* values to be missing sometimes and handle them without catching an exception. I'm finding the question hard to understand, but I would expect to be able to fix this without catching any exceptions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested. Add the full exception message you get and what output/result you want instead. Please read [ask] on how to increase the quality of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [?. null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) on properties that have potential of being `null`.

Here is a modified version of your method that returns `null`, instead of throwing an exception, when a *product*, *variant* or *CompareAtPrice* is `null`:

```
private decimal? GetComparePrice(long? productId, long? variantId, List<Product> products)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId);
    var variant = product?.Variants?.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == variantId);
    return variant?.CompareAtPrice;
}
```

Here is a [link to run this example via .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XsbGkW).